# Shorten Query run time with fetch next/first

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running this statement in toad for Oracle:

```
select *
from hourly_analysis 
where eff_date like '%JAN-18'
fetch next 10 rows only
```

I added the `fetch 10 rows only` in hopes that it would shorten my query run time bc it is currently running for 1 hour +. is there a reason why it is still running so long and how else could I shorten the query run time

Comment: `eff_date like '%JAN-18'` is probably the problem. Column eff_date data type?

Comment: it is DATE data type

Comment: Use something like:  eff_date BETWEEN ‘2018-01-01’ and ‘2018-01-31’

Comment: OK, JAN is probably January. What is 18? 18th of January? The whole January of year 2018? Something else? Basically, you should compare **dates**, not date with a string. Also, index on eff_date would probably help. FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY probably won't. Also, consider explaining what exactly you're doing. Sample data and desired result might also help us help you.

Comment: it is january of year 2018

Comment: The database still has to evaluate the `WHERE` clause on **ALL** of the rows in the table to know which rows might be included, and `eff_date like '%JAN-18'` is about as bad as it gets for checking a specific month.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, does Oracle really go thru the whole table even after 10 rows has been found?

Comment: @jarlh In this case it will, because of the "Next". That implies an order of some kind, so it needs to build the full potential result set to know which rows are the next 10.

Comment: More than one hour for a full table scan? How huge is that table? Sounds like a disk problem to me. I doubt there is any difference between `FETCH FIRST` and `FETCH NEXT`, they are just to choose which you prefer for readability (same as with `ROW` and `ROWS`). There is no `ORDER BY` clause, so the DBMS can just read the table sequentially until 10 matches are found. Anyway maybe there are no matches, then the whole table must be read. But one hour?

Comment: Anyway, your approach is bad. You treat the date like a string, so the DBMS has to convert it. Your `where eff_date like '%JAN-18'` becomes `where to_string(eff_date) like '%JAN-18'` internally. And as no explicit format is given, the DBMS uses the session format for the conversion. If the session format is 'mm/dd/yyyy' for instance, `like '%JAN-18'` won't match any date. Only if the session happens to be set to `'somethingMON-YY` and the language happens to be English, then will the comparison work...

Comment: Never rely on implicit conversions. You could make the conversion explicit with the desired format, but much better is to just deal with dates as shown in jarlh's answer. And their recommendation to index the date column then is good advice, too, for this query.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
select *
from hourly_analysis 
where eff_date >= date '2018-01-01' and eff_date < date '2018-02-01';
```

And make sure eff_date is indexed.

Thanks to ThorstenKettner for telling *As Oracle misnamed their datetime type DATE, many users fall into the trap to name their columns DATE when they are datetimes actually. So despite the name eff_date, the column might contain times as well.* and also providing a correction to the WHERE clause!

Comment: As Oracle misnamed their datetime type `DATE`, many users fall into the trap to name their columns `DATE` when they are datetimes actually. So despite the name `eff_date`, the column might contain times as well. It is hence safer to use `where eff_date >= date '2018-01-01' and eff_date < date '2018-02-01'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, oops. Thank you for the information, I had no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

The database still has to evaluate the `WHERE` clause on **ALL** of the rows in the table to know which rows might be included and which are "NEXT". With that in mind, the `eff_date like '%JAN-18'` expression is about as bad as it gets for checking a specific month.

So let's look at some real fixes:

1. If you MUST use a string, format the values so the elements come in order from most-significant on the left to least-significant on the right. That is, year, then month, then day, then hour, etc. At least then you wouldn't need a leading wildcard, and an index just *might*, if you're very lucky, still be useful.
2. But don't. Use a data type from the `DateTime` family instead of a string. This will improve storage and memory use, give you access to the date functions, and generally help with performance and accuracy overall. It's a BIG DEAL.
3. Once you *fix the column* (because putting dates in a varchar column really is a **broken** schema) to use a datetime value, match the criteria to your stored values instead of matching the stored values to your criteria.

   What does that mean? In this case, instead of looking at just the month and year of the value in the column, you can leave the column values unchanged and get the same logical result using this expression:

   ```
    where eff_date >= '2008-01-01' and eff_date < '2008-02-01'
   ```

   The two comparisons will be MUCH FASTER because there are no per-row conversions needed and any index on the column will still be relevant. This cuts to the core of database performance. Also note how I used an *exclusive* upper boundary on the moment just after the desired range. This avoids certain kinds of errors where you may have an unexpected time component as part of the data.

Comment: When I implemented FETCH FIRST/NEXT I decided to quit reading the table when the desired number of rows had been found. Very simple when no ORDER BY clause is involved.